# Add ListView item to tabbed Fragment in Android

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, android-listview, android-viewpager

I'm trying to add an item to a ListView (when a button is pushed) in a specific tab. I want the item to be added to the tab the user is currently in. FYI: I'm using Android Studio's default ActionBar tab Fragment template. Also, I'm using a custom adapter if that makes any difference.

I am able to add and item to the listview, but it is inconsistent and doesn't always work. Sometimes, when I click the button, nothing happens, other times, my new item appears on another page/tab. Also, after a bit of scrolling back and forth between tabs, items that did show up will suddenly disappear.

Any help would be appreciated.

Here is the Fragment:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ListView;

import com.supercilex.common.ListViewAdapter;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import static com.supercilex.robotscouter.tempNewForm.PlaceholderFragment.addItemToList;

public class tempNewForm extends AppCompatActivity
{
    private static ArrayList< String > textViewValues;
    private static ArrayList< String > checkBoxValues;
    private static ListViewAdapter     listViewAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate ( Bundle savedInstanceState )
    {
        super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );
        setContentView( R.layout.activity_temp_new_form );

        Toolbar toolbar = ( Toolbar ) findViewById( R.id.toolbar );
        setSupportActionBar( toolbar );
        // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
        // primary sections of the activity.
        SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter( getSupportFragmentManager() );

        // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
        ViewPager mViewPager = ( ViewPager ) findViewById( R.id.container );
        mViewPager.setAdapter( mSectionsPagerAdapter );


        TabLayout tabLayout = ( TabLayout ) findViewById( R.id.tabs );
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager( mViewPager );

        FloatingActionButton fab = ( FloatingActionButton ) findViewById( R.id.fab );
        fab.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick ( View view )
            {
                addItemToList(
                        "test",
                        "test2"
                             );

                Snackbar.make(
                        view,
                        "Replace with your own action",
                        Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG
                             )
                        .setAction(
                                "Action",
                                null
                                  )
                        .show();
            }
        } );
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu ( Menu menu )
    {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(
                R.menu.menu_temp_new_form,
                menu
                                 );
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected ( MenuItem item )
    {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if ( id == R.id.action_settings )
        {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected( item );
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment
    {

        /**
         * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
         * fragment.
         */
        private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

        public PlaceholderFragment ()
        {
        }

        /**
         * Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section
         * number.
         */
        public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance ( int sectionNumber )
        {
            PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
            Bundle              args     = new Bundle();
            args.putInt(
                    ARG_SECTION_NUMBER,
                    sectionNumber
                       );
            fragment.setArguments( args );
            return fragment;
        }

        public static void addItemToList (
                String textViewValue,
                String checkboxValue
                                         )
        {
            textViewValues.add( textViewValue );
            checkBoxValues.add( checkboxValue );
            listViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView (
                LayoutInflater inflater,
                ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState
                                 )
        {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(
                    R.layout.fragment_temp_new_form,
                    container,
                    false
                                            );

            textViewValues = new ArrayList<>();
            checkBoxValues = new ArrayList<>();

            ListView listView = ( ListView ) rootView.findViewById( R.id.listView3 );
rootView.findViewById( R.id.fragment_temp_new_form_layout );
            switch ( getArguments().getInt( ARG_SECTION_NUMBER ) )
            {
                case 1:
                    textViewValues.add( "Android List View from " + getArguments().getInt( ARG_SECTION_NUMBER ) );

                    checkBoxValues.add( "first from " + getArguments().getInt( ARG_SECTION_NUMBER ) );
                    break;
                case 2:
                    textViewValues.add( "Android List View from " + getArguments().getInt( ARG_SECTION_NUMBER ) );

                    checkBoxValues.add( "first from " + getArguments().getInt( ARG_SECTION_NUMBER ) );
                    break;
                case 3:
                    textViewValues.add( "Android List View from " + getArguments().getInt( ARG_SECTION_NUMBER ) );

                    checkBoxValues.add( "first from " + getArguments().getInt( ARG_SECTION_NUMBER ) );
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }

            listViewAdapter = new ListViewAdapter(
                    getContext(),
                    textViewValues,
                    checkBoxValues
            );
            listView.setAdapter( listViewAdapter );
            return rootView;
        }
    }

    /**
     * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to
     * one of the sections/tabs/pages.
     */
    public static class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter
    {
        public SectionsPagerAdapter ( FragmentManager fm )
        {
            super( fm );
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem ( int position )
        {
            // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
            // Return a PlaceholderFragment (defined as a static inner class below).
            return PlaceholderFragment.newInstance( position + 1 );
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount ()
        {
            // Show x total pages.
            return 3;
        }

        @Nullable
        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle ( int position )
        {
            switch ( position )
            {
                case 0:
                    return "TAB 1";
                case 1:
                    return "TAB 2";
                case 2:
                    return "TAB 3";
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my custom adapter:

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.supercilex.robotscouter.R;
import com.supercilex.robotscouter.tempNewForm;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter
{
    private final ArrayList< String > textViewValues;
    private final ArrayList< String > checkBoxValues;
    private final Context             context;

    public ListViewAdapter (
            Context context,
            ArrayList< String > textViewValues,
            ArrayList< String > checkBoxValues
                           )
    {
        this.textViewValues = textViewValues;
        this.checkBoxValues = checkBoxValues;
        this.context = context;
        correctArrays();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount ()
    {
        if ( ( textViewValues != null || textViewValues.size() != 0 ) || ( checkBoxValues != null || checkBoxValues.size() != 0 ) )
        {
            if ( textViewValues.size() >= checkBoxValues.size() )
            {
                return textViewValues.size();
            }
            else
            {
                return checkBoxValues.size();
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem ( int position )
    {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId ( int position )
    {
        return position;
    }

    @SuppressLint ( "InflateParams" )
    @Override
    public View getView (
            final int position,
            View convertView,
            ViewGroup parent
                        )
    {
        View convertView1 = convertView;
        if ( convertView1 == null )
        {
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
            layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from( context.getApplicationContext() );
            convertView1 = layoutInflater.inflate(
                    R.layout.list_view_layout,
                    null
                                                 );
        }

        TextView textView = ( TextView ) convertView1.findViewById( R.id.rowTextView );
        CheckBox checkBox = ( CheckBox ) convertView1.findViewById( R.id.listViewCheckBox );

        if ( textViewValues.get( position )
                           .equals( "null" ) )
        {
            textView.setVisibility( View.GONE );
        }
        else
        {
            textView.setVisibility( View.VISIBLE );
            textView.setText( textViewValues.get( position ) );
        }

        if ( checkBoxValues.get( position )
                           .equals( "null" ) )
        {
            checkBox.setVisibility( View.GONE );
        }
        else
        {
            checkBox.setVisibility( View.VISIBLE );
            checkBox.setText( checkBoxValues.get( position ) );
        }

        convertView1.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick ( View view )
            {
                if ( context.getClass()
                            .toString()
                            .equals( "class com.supercilex.robotscouter.MainActivity" ) )
                {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(
                            view.getContext(),
                            tempNewForm.class
                    );
                    context.startActivity( intent );
                }

                // Show Alert
                Snackbar.make(
                        view,
                        "Position: " + position + "  ListItem: " + textViewValues.get( position ),
                        Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG
                             )
                        .setAction(
                                "Action",
                                null
                                  )
                        .show();
            }
        } );
        return convertView1;
    }

    private void correctArrays ()
    {
        if ( textViewValues.size() > checkBoxValues.size() )
        {
            for (
                    int i = checkBoxValues.size();
                    i < textViewValues.size();
                    i++
                    )
            {
                checkBoxValues.add(
                        i,
                        "null"
                                  );
            }
        }
        else if ( textViewValues.size() < checkBoxValues.size() )
        {
            for (
                    int i = textViewValues.size();
                    i < checkBoxValues.size();
                    i++
                    )
            {
                textViewValues.add(
                        i,
                        "null"
                                  );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: and what is your question exactly? what problems are you having?

Comment: Sorry, I was adding code and forgot to finish my question. Hope my updated question helps.